# Add a user for Postgres on Mac

Tags: osx, users

I've had a very difficult time trying to set up a postgres database. I am using Mac OS X 10.9.2.

I am using this tutorial: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/environment/environment.html

The Postgres section can be found 2/3 of the way down the page.

After installing Homebrew and commanding `brew install postgresql`

we create a database by:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/pgsql/data
sudo chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
sudo su postgres
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
createuser `whoami`
```

When I do

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

it returns the error

```
chown: postgres: illegal user name
```

I can't seem to find a simple command to add a user - adduser and useradd have returned "command not found", with and without sudo. I am not sure what the problem is. Is there a simple command I can do?

Comment: Well, is there a user named "postgres" on your system?

Comment: You likely don't have a `postgres` user on your system. Try creating one by running `sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres`

Comment: Refer to this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6815565/1245380

Answer (score 1):

If the username is not existent, you should not have been able to enter a login session using `su`. MacOS uses a [Directory Service](https://superuser.com/a/191333) to store and keep track of user accounts. Create the user account (and respective group, as the syntax of chown is `chown user:group /path/to/file/or/dir`) using dscl and [dseditgroup](https://superuser.com/a/214311) prior to attempting to chown files/directories to it:

```
sudo dscl . create /Groups/postgres
sudo dscl . create /Users/postgres
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a postgres -t user postgres
```

More advanced settings (UIDs, Group description and passwords) are possible [too](https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/create-groups-using-dscl/).